# Why is a certain replacement rule not succeeding?

Tags: replacement

I've been trying to apply the replacement rule

```
/. Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 l3) (2 - l3 + 2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])] -> (1 - 
2 l3 + Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])
```

on certain sums of terms (some of which have Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 l3) (2 - l3 + 2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])] present in them and some don't.

But it doesn't seem to "take".

Well, as a "minimal example", requested by Henrik Schumacher, I tried applying the rule (extracted from the problem at hand) to

```
{(35273081594445401718784 l3^12 Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 l3) (2 - l3 + 
 2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])])/3712593527476531425, -((968284000367625764864 l3^13 Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 l3) (2 - l3 + 
  2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])])/343180914304553325)}
```

without the hoped-for-transformation taking place. (This was being done in Version Number 11.3.0.0--which I presume shouldn't be making a difference.)

Comment: Hm. This is hard so tell without a minimal example...

Comment: Hm. It evaluates under version 12.0 to the modified expression without any problems. Have your tried to restart your kernel? Sometimes weird things happen with hanging definitions...

Comment: Good idea, Henrik! I'll try it.

Comment: Totally impossible! Restarted my laptop--same result. Can't even seem to do work-arounds--like using CoefficientList. (By possible way of explanation, I'm working now on a home laptop without the "64-bit (Intel)" .)  For some reason, that expression Sqrt[-(-1 + 2 l3) (2 - l3 + 2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])] doesn't seem to get recognized at all.

Comment: Actually--to tell the truth-I did get the replacement to work once--but not again!

Comment: The similar rule /. Sqrt[(1 + l3) (2 - l3 + 2 Sqrt[1 - l3 - 2 l3^2])] -> ((Sqrt[
     1 - l3 - 2 l3^2]) - (-1 - l3)) works without a problem.